# Programming HyperlinkColumn to Send an Email WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, email, outlook

I am attempting to program a `DataGridHyperlinkColumn` which contains user's emails to send a new email through outlook when clicking on the address. For now I am just using a test email instead of getting the contents of the column, but this is what I have so far;

```
<DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Email}">
    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style>
            <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="OnEmailHyperlinkClick"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
```

Then the handler in C#;

```
private void OnEmailHyperlinkClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string subject = "My subject";
    string emailTag = string.Format("mailto:someone@test.com?subject={0}", subject);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(emailTag);
}
```

At the moment this is providing strange behaviour. First of all it opens a new instance of Google Chrome. Nothing to do with Outlook at at all. It then crashes saying;

*Cannot locate resource 'addressbook/someone@test.com'*

It's almost as if this event is actually being handled elsewhere, but I am lamost certain it isn't. Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

All that your solution does is tells windows to try to start a new process using the provided string.

You need to specify that you want it to use outlook.

Add the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` reference to your project (make sure it's the correct version)

Then try something like this:

```
public static void OnEmailHyperlinkClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

                MailItem msg = (MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);

                msg.Subject = "My subject";

                msg.Body = "My Message Body";

                Recipients recipients = (Recipients)msg.Recipients;

                Recipient recipient = (Recipient)recipients.Add("someone@test.com");
                recipient.Resolve();

                msg.Display(); // If you want to have the email displayed for the user to send
                // Otherwise
                msg.Send();

                recipient = null;
                recipients = null;
                msg = null;
                oApp = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This now does open an email in `Outlook` instead of a tab in Chrome, however I still get the error `Cannot locate resource 'addressbook/someone@test.com'`. Any advice?

Comment: Is `someone@test.com` in the outlook address book? Try using it with a real email address instead.